# Jquery autocomplete with dynamic input fields not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have created multiple dynamic input fields but I want to add jquery autocomplete with all the input fields but problem is this is only working with only first input field not with every dynamically added input fields. I have tried many SO answers but none of them are working for me or May be I could not understand.

Someone will help me with this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Dynamic add/remove input fields in PHP Jquery AJAX</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="card text-center" style="margin-bottom:50px;">
  <h1>Dynamic Add/Remove input fields in PHP Jquery AJAX</h1>
</div>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="form-group">
          <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="dynamic_field">
              <tr>
                  <td> 
                    
                  
                  <div class="ui-widget">
      
        <td><input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
    </div>
                  

                <td><input type="text" name="name[]"  id="automplete-2" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email[]" placeholder="Enter your Email" class="form-control name_email"/></td>
                <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-primary">Add More</button></td>  
              </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

 
       
                <?php
               

               $js_array = json_encode($name);
               echo "var availableTutorials  = ". $js_array . ";\n";
              
               
                ?>
            
            $("#automplete-2").autocomplete({
                source: availableTutorials,
                autoFocus: true
            });

          


    var i = 1;

    $("#add").click(function(){
      i++;
      $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text"  id="automplete-2"  name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list"/></td><td><input type="text" name="email[]" placeholder="Enter your Email" class="form-control name_email"/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
    });
 

    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
      var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
      $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
    });

    $("#submit").on('click',function(){
      var formdata = $("#add_name").serialize();
      $.ajax({
        url   :"action.php",
        type  :"POST",
        data  :formdata,
        cache :false,
        success:function(result){
          alert(result);
          $("#add_name")[0].reset();
        }
      });
    });
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I read the code again and i find this solution and it's working now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Dynamic add/remove input fields in PHP Jquery AJAX</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="card text-center" style="margin-bottom:50px;">
  <h1>Dynamic Add/Remove input fields in PHP Jquery AJAX</h1>
</div>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="form-group">
          <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="dynamic_field">
              <tr>
                  <td> 
                    
                  
                  <div class="ui-widget">
      
        <td><input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
    </div>
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
                
                <td><input type="text" name="name[]"  id="automplete-2" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email[]" placeholder="Enter your Email" class="form-control name_email"/></td>
                <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-primary">Add More</button></td>  
              </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

 
     

    var i = 1;

    $("#add").click(function(){
      i++;
      $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text"  id="automplete-2"  name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list"/></td><td><input type="text" name="email[]" placeholder="Enter your Email" class="form-control name_email"/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
          
      $('#dynamic_field').find('input[name^="name"]').autocomplete({
                source:  availableTutorials
            });   
    });
 

    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
      var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
      $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
    });

    $("#submit").on('click',function(){
      var formdata = $("#add_name").serialize();
      $.ajax({
        url   :"action.php",
        type  :"POST",
        data  :formdata,
        cache :false,
        success:function(result){
          alert(result);
          $("#add_name")[0].reset();
        }
      });
    });
      
    <?php
               

               $js_array = json_encode($name);
               echo "var availableTutorials  = ". $js_array . ";\n";
              
               
                ?>
            
            // $("#dynamic_field").autocomplete({
            //     source: availableTutorials,
            //     autoFocus: true
            // });
            $("input[name^='name']").autocomplete({
        source: availableTutorials
    }); 

          

  });













</script>
```